# Как декодировать шетснадцатеричные строки?

Tags: hex, reverse-engineering, decode

Наткнулся на большой датасет с морем строк такого формата:

```
.,2EB1E083-8D7B-70AC-728D946F,. .,f153d57025e6a82cb116847ab1679dfb6ccdce6d3b8d5e157cfa1392ed272d99,.
```

Известно что `.,`, `,. .,` и `,.` - просто разделители (сепараторы). Также известно что по этим строкам некая программа идентифицирует пользователя (каждая строка - один пользователь). Пробовал получить цифры из обоих строк, вычитал и складывал так и эдак, но смысловой нагрузки не нашел. Перевод в байты и последующее декодирование в текст с помощью ASCII и UTF-8 успешно выдало ошибку. Ссылка на полный список таких вот строк - https://pastebin.com/G4avzuWY

UPDATE: Нашел некий "хэш": `8c36befca2a0ad82ffadc442bd6391bed8fcf855a398f3a8652332d087cf2afe`. Возможно он чем-то поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строки вида `2EB1E083-8D7B-70AC-728D946F`, которые Вы привели в начале вопроса, содержат GUID-ы - глобальные уникальные идентификаторы.

Декодировать их не имеет смысла, они сделаны специально так, чтобы не повторяться. Это просто айдишники

Видимо, датасет содержит информацию о связи одних "штук", идентифицируемых такими айди с другими "штуками". Относитесь к ним просто как к специальному типу данных. Имеет смысл проанализировать файл на "повторяемость" таких ID - шников.

Содержательная информация может содержаться в более длинных строках. Если это - хэши, то, скорее всего, гадать, что превратилось в такой хеш - не имеет смысла.

По внешнему виду "более длинные" строки наподобие `f153d57025e6a82cb116847ab1679dfb6ccdce6d3b8d5e157cfa1392ed272d99` похожи на результат работы хэша `SHA-512`, но хэш на то и хэш, что простого "обратного преобразования" не существует.

Можно попробовать прошерстить другие датасеты, или сделать предположения о том, что могут означать эти ID (например, поискать их в блокчейне и т.п.) - но здесь поле поиска чрезвычайно широко.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение левой части строки! Может, вы знаете какой-нибудь алгоритм который создаёт строки наподобие строк в правой части (после `,. .,`)?

Comment: @твояdeadline - я немного дополнил ответ